# How to go past window 9 in GNU Screen without going to Window list?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I use GNU Screen tool to keep my sessions alive on the system.  To switch between windows I use `Ctrl+a N` where N is the number of the window.  I want to use similar keystroke to access windows with numbers in two digits.  As of now I have to go to window list by `Ctrl+a "` and then select the window.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> (an apostrophe), `screen` asks you to enter the window number.  It's in `screen` help on the left side. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> to see the help.

Comment: This should be written as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>?</kbd> respectively or something similar to indicate not all three keys are pressed at the same time. Since that markup seems disabled in comments: That's Ctrl+a,' or Ctrl+a,? respectively.

Answer (score 8):

According to screen's manual page, you can add the following lines to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
bind -c demo1 0 select 10
bind -c demo1 1 select 11
bind -c demo1 2 select 12
bindkey "^B" command -c demo1
```

makes `C-b 0` select window 10, `C-b 1` window 11, etc. Alternatively, you can use:

```
bind -c demo2 0 select 10
bind -c demo2 1 select 11
bind -c demo2 2 select 12
bind - command -c demo2
```

makes `C-a - 0` select window 10, `C-a - 1` window 11, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know what your doing that actually needs 10+ processes to be accessible in one screen instance anyway, but you might just use `ctrl-a n/p` to go back and forth (which conveniently wraps around).

And consider just using 2 instances of screen ... or even a screen-in-screen

There is no way to switch directly to windows above number 9 as explained in [the doc.](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Select)

Comment: Having 9+ processes in Screen is not the case always but sometimes I do have 12-13 processes running and I need to watch them at the same time.  Looks like I'll have to stick with `Ctrl+a "`.

Comment: you can have a split screen too. Which works nice if you want to have more processes open at the same time. Maybe [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) could be useful too

Comment: the initial comment is completely unnecessary. having more than 10 windows in screen for me is commonplace, I do different things in different directories in each and it's much more productive to have one window per task (watch logs, edit sources, run stuff, monitor results, etc).

Comment: I sometimes open a separate window to each server of the same cluster, so it's rather common for me to have more than 10 windows. thanks.